# How to run a pandas command iteratively and get the results as a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a dynamic list of names `ALL_NAMES`

Every day a different length, but today for this question it has 3 elements:

```
ALL_NAMES = ['alpha', 'betha', 'gamma']
```

I'd like to run a single-valued pandas-SQL-query iterated over these elements and have the resulting information in one list as in this conceptual `for`-loop:

```
>>> import pandas, pyodbc

>>> connection = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={"+'Driver'+"};SERVER="+'SQL'+";DATABASE="+'DB'+";Trusted_Connection=yes") 

>>> for i in range(len(ALL_NAMES)):
...  execute "pandas.read_sql_query(\"select * from [schema].[" + ALL_NAMES[i] + "]\", connection).Column[index]"
...  LIST = merged_results_to_one_list
```

As a result I want something like this

```
>>> LIST
[17, 43, 12]
```

For now, I am able to do the following process:

1. Change `execute` for `print` and get:

```
>>> for i in range(len(ALL_NAMES)):
...  print("pandas.read_sql_query(\"select * from [schema].[" + ALL_NAMES[i] + "]\", connection).Column[index]")

pandas.read_sql_query("select * from [schema].[alpha]", connection).Column[index]
pandas.read_sql_query("select * from [schema].[betha]", connection).Column[index]
pandas.read_sql_query("select * from [schema].[gamma]", connection).Column[index]
```

2. put this lines in a `.py`-file,
3. run it as a Python script,
4. parse the results somehow and get the list I am looking for

But something tells me there are better ways. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test this without the database, but shouldn't something like the following work?

```py
LIST = []

for name in ALL_NAMES:
    LIST.append(pandas.read_sql_query("select * from [schema].[" + name + "]\", 
                                      connection).Column[index])
```

Comment: hello, yes! that does the trick! I missed to understand that the text written within the ```for```-loop is always a command! useless of me to use ```print(...)```, and wise of you to point the list initialization and ```appent```!